# Фигура из символов

Tags: c++, циклы, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Недавно начал изучать С++, и мой код хромает. Нужно вывести следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно укоротить мой код(уверен, что можно)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    string simvol = "*";
    
    int control = 7;

    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        cout << simvol << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        if ((j == 0) || (j == control - 1)) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << simvol << " ";
        }   
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        if ((j == 0) || (j == 1) || (j == control - 1) || (j == control - 2)) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << simvol << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        if ((j == 0) || (j == 1) || (j == 2) || (j == control - 1) || (j == control - 2) || (j == control - 3)) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << simvol << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        if ((j == 0) || (j == 1) || (j == control - 1) || (j == control - 2)) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << simvol << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        if ((j == 0) || (j == control - 1)) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        else {
            cout << simvol << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < control; j++) {
        cout << simvol << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так годится?

```
int main()
{
    int N = 7;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            cout << (((j >= i && j < N-i) || (j <= i && j >= N-i-1)) ? "* " : "  ");
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

См. https://ideone.com/qzhiIx

P.S. Ну, или если ровно для 7 —

```
int main()
{
    cout << "* * * * * * *\n  * * * * *\n    * * *\n"
        "      *\n    * * *\n  * * * * *\n* * * * * * *\n";
}
```

:)

Comment: а что в cout значит знак вопроса и двоеточие?

Comment: [Тернарный оператор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)

Comment: Интересно, кому и почему в этот раз ответ не нравится? Или стыдно признаться, почему? :)

Comment: с чего вы решили, что ответ кому-то не понравился? Он просто отличный!

Comment: Ну кто-то же поставил минус? :)

Comment: я Вам ставлю плюс)

Comment: :) Спасибо, но мне очень интересно, что же именно не нравится человеку, поставившему минус, но не сказавшему, почему, и не давшему своего решения...

Comment: Не знаю, код понятен и прост, да и помогли вы мне) тут сплошные плюсы)